# hadoop CustomWritables

Tags: hadoop, writable

I have more of a design question regarding the necessity of a CustomWritable for my use case:

So I have a document pair that I will process through a pipeline and write out intermediate and final data to HDFS. My key will be something like ObjectId - DocId - Pair - Lang. I do not see why/if I will need a CustomWritable for this use case. I guess if I did not have a key, I would need a CustomWritable? Also, when I write data out to HDFS in the Reducer, I use a Custom Partitioner. So, that would kind of eliminate my need for a Custom Writable?

I am not sure if I got the concept of the need for a Custom Writable right. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Of course I am going to read up Yahoo's tutorial and Tom White's book now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writables can be used for de/serializing objects. For example a log entry can contain a timestamp, an user IP and the browser agent. So you should implement your own WritableComparable for a key that identifies this entry and you should implement a value class that implements Writable that reads and writes the attributes in your log entry.

These serializations are just a handy way to get the data from a binary format to an object. Some Frameworks like HBase still require byte arrays to persist the data. So you'll have a lot of overhead in transfering this by yourself and messes up your code.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I guess since am dealing with String keys, I wouldnt need to implement WritableComparable.

Comment: No, you can just go for the Text class. GL

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut is right.You can have a look into [writing Custom Writable](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id3548156#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODA1OTY1MjE5NzQlMkZpZDM1NDgxNTYmcXVlcnk9)

Answer (score 0):

Thomas' answer explains a bit. Its way too late but I'd like to add the following for prospective readers:

Partitioner only comes into play between the map and reduce phase and has no role to play in writing from reducer to output files.

I don't believe writing INTERMEDIATE data to hdfs is a requirement in most cases, although there are some hacks that can be applied to do the same.

When you write from a reducer to hdfs, the keys will automatically be sorted and each reducer will write to ONE SEPARATE file. Based on their `compareTo` method, keys are sorted. So if you want to sort based on multiple variables, go for a Custom key class that extends `WritableComparable`, and implement the `write`, `readFields` and `compareTo` methods. You can now control the way the keys are sorted, based on the `compareTo` implementation